# Qu'est-ce que c'est que

Tags: grammaire, interrogative

I was taught that one ought to use "qu'est-ce que c'est que..." to ask what something specific is. Is there any way around this construction, that is, is it possible to remove the final "que"?

I saw the sentence, "qu'est-ce qu'un dîner sans vin?" and I also saw the sentence "qu'est-ce que c'est qu'un symbole?". Are both of these sentences correct, and why? What is the rule? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the final *que* is possible but would lead to a slight pause:

> *Qu'est-ce que c'est, un dîner sans vin ?*

Removing *que c'est* from the long form will raise its formality from spoken French to standard French without substantially changing the meaning:

> *Qu'est-ce que c'est qu'un dîner sans vin ?* (or *C'est quoi, un dîner sans vin ?*)
>
> *Qu'est-ce qu'un dîner sans vin ?*

It is possible to go even further and write:

> *Qu'est un dîner sans vin ?*

This is formal and literary and the meaning is also slightly stronger. Here the question is rhetorical.

Same for *qu'est-ce que c'est qu'un symbole ?* although *qu'est un symbole ?* is not very idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you. So if I were writing an essay in French, for example, I ought to omit the "que c'est"? Also, I've heard that "quoi" is only used as an object to a preposition, but you did not use it in this way in your answer. Can "quoi" only be used after a preposition? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, dropping *que c'est* would improve the style. *Que* is used before the verb while *quoi* is used after the verb: *Que veut cet homme ?* = *Cet homme veut quoi ?* (informal)

Comment: Okay, merci beaucoup.